# Spring data Mongodb return Page<java.util.Map>

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a use-case where I need to create collections on the fly and query them with pagination applied. Basically I need the following functions

```
Page<? extends Map<String, ?>> findAll(Pageable pageable);
Page<? extends Map<String, ?>> find(Query query, Pageable pageable);
```

Can I use Spring data MongoDB classes to achieve this?

**Environment:**

- Spring - 3.2.2
- Spring Data Commons - 1.6.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- Spring Data Mongo - 1.3.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT